# Why does the subsurf modifier display a "Hide, mask and optimized display disabled" message when sculpting?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

When I paint with the mask brush, nothing changes and the mask area is not visible in sculpt mode. I get this message in the modifier panel:

[image]

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: It's the modifier. It doesn't work in sculpt mode. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/197052/107598 how to disable it temporarily.