# Blender wouldn't paint neither face sets not the mask anymore

Tags: sculpting, masking

I got blender into a somewhat strange state after I decided to add some vertex colours to my sculpt for better visibility.

As I load the save file I cannot paint the face sets anymore, not can I paint the mask. 'Invert mask' would do nothing.

Creating a new mesh and trying to sculpt it won't work.

Effectively, I'm forced to go back to my older save, or copy everything to a new document.

I think the only things I did to get here was:

- set up the vertex paint material
- tinker with the viewport display to show vertex colours
- actually paint some over the mesh

Any advice on how can I force the document back into an usable state?

Note 1: Here's the [blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yRWxYA8MhnWXuyyL_Wd8StPobkFq4OMK/view?usp=sharing) file featuring the problem.

Note 2: The overlays are indeed enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Armature`. `Modifiers` prevent Hide, Mask, and Facesets in Sculpt mode. Usually, you get a warning like this:

[image: Warning active modifiers in sculpt mode]

`Armature`, `Cloth`, and Hair/`Particles`, and all the other physics are also Modifiers. It's probably a bug that Blender doesn't warn you if you have one of these 3 activated. (`Dynamic Paint` gives you a warning.)

To see your Facesets and Mask in Sculpt Mode again you just have to disable the Armature modifier in viewport render by clicking the little icon that looks like a monitor.

[image: Sculpt mode with disabled modifiers]

Make sure your Faceset overlays are enabled. It's not enabled in the uploaded blend file ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out on this! It was driving me crazy that after copying everything to anew blend file I managed to eventually (by adding the rig) break it there as well.